# HTML: Align dinamically generated buttons in to be in the middle of a column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I'm creating a series of dynamically generated elments. One of these elements is composed of two multiple choice lists with arrow buttons int the middle. The idea is for this to be "add" and "remove" from two lists of elements.

Here is the code that is generated:

```
<div class="item form-group">
   <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="components">Components</label>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class = "row">
         <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-lg-5">
            <select class="select2_multiple form-control" id=components multiple="multiple">
            <option value="0"> Option 0</option>
            <option value="1"> Option 1</option>
            <option value="2"> Option 2</option>
            <option value="3"> Option 3</option>
            <option value="4"> Option 4</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 col-lg-2">
            <div class = "row">
               <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12">
               <button type ="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "row" style="margin-top:20%">
               <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" col-lg-12>
               <button type ="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></button>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-lg-5">
            <select class="select2_multiple form-control" id=components-out multiple="multiple">
            <option value="0"> Option 0</option>
            <option value="1"> Option 1</option>
            <option value="2"> Option 2</option>
            <option value="3"> Option 3</option>
            <option value="4"> Option 4</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And here is how it displays:

[image]

I like it. My only question is how can I get the two button to be centered with respect to the multiple choice boxes? I figure I need to center teh buttons in their columns, but the code I have found is not working.

I'm using boostrap 3 and Gentella which came with tha version of bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `align-self-center` class to the middle column should do the trick, I have commented below where I made changes:

```html
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="item form-group">
   <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="components">Components</label>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class = "row justify-content-center" >
         <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-lg-5">
            <select class="select2_multiple form-control" id=components multiple="multiple">
            <option value="0"> Option 0</option>
            <option value="1"> Option 1</option>
            <option value="2"> Option 2</option>
            <option value="3"> Option 3</option>
            <option value="4"> Option 4</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <!-- start edit -->
         <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 col-lg-2 align-self-center">
         <!-- stop edit -->
            <div class = "row">
               <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12">
               <button type ="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "row" style="margin-top:20%">
               <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" col-lg-12>
               <button type ="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></button>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-lg-5">
            <select class="select2_multiple form-control" id=components-out multiple="multiple">
            <option value="0"> Option 0</option>
            <option value="1"> Option 1</option>
            <option value="2"> Option 2</option>
            <option value="3"> Option 3</option>
            <option value="4"> Option 4</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

ps: open the snippet in full page to view the intended implementation

Also do well to check out the grid system section of the Bootstrap docs to further improve your bootstrap-grid implementation: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: I'm sorry. But this doesn't do what I want. I want the button to be one below the other and not right beside each other. But thanks for the attempt

Comment: @aarelovich, Oh I get your question now, I have edited my answer by the way, check it. Another possible approach is to add a margin style to the middle column as so `style=" margin:6.25% 0 "`

Comment: Thank you again. Your answers seems to do what I'm looking for but it doesn't seem to work with Boostrap 3. I have tried to upgrade before and gotten disastrous results so I'm just leaving it, as is.